# How can I create a TableView with a specific amount of row and autogenerated column in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Im stuck with this problem.

I need to crate a table with limited row that expands the columns based on the elements of a list.

I thought about creating limited sub-lists of objects and then putting them one by one on the table. Unfortunately, however, it does not work and I do not know what to do

```
    for(int i=0;i<opera.getLista().size()-f;) { //cycle the list
        RandomString session = new RandomString(); //give a random name to the column
        TableColumn<ContenutoOpera,ImageView> column = new TableColumn<>(session.nextString()); //create a column
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Image"));//set the column
          tabella2.getColumns().add(column);//add the column
          Cont=Cont+1;//it dosn't do enything
          if(opera.getLista().size()==10) {//if the list size =10 get the sub-list, set the table and set the list counter to the max
              tabella2.getItems().setAll(opera.getLista(f));
          f=opera.getList().size();
          }else 
              if(opera.getLista().size()>10) {//if the list size > 10 get the sub-list, set the table and add 10 the the list counter
                  tabella2.getItems().setAll(opera.getLista(f));
                  f=f+10;
              }
              else
                  if(opera.getLista().size()<10) {//if the list size<10 get the sub-list size()-f+1 are the cycle that the for will do to add items to the list , set the table and set the list counter to the max
                      tabella2.getItems().setAll(opera.getLista1(opera.getLista().size()-f+1,f));
            f=opera.getLista().size();    
}

    }
```

ignore any syntax errors, the logic does not work anyway

Comment: Did You try coming up with Your solution? Maybe some sample code?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: i've added the code